# Alter query with posts_clauses to retrieve NULL values last

Tags: query, mysql

I'm running a query to order my posts first by book's author, and then by book's name.
I'm trying to achieve something like this :

Author A : Book A

Author A : Book B

Author B : Book F

Author C : Book C

NULL : Book D

and so on... I'm running this query :

```
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'ouvrages',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value auteur titre',
       'meta_query' => array(
            'auteur' => array(
                'key' => 'auteur',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'titre' => array(
                'key' => 'titre',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
        ),
        'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

I'm trying to alter the query with posts_clauses, but I'm not really familiar with MySQL syntax.
How can I alter the [orderby] clause in posts_clauses to retrieve 'auteur' meta_key's NULL values last instead of first ?

Thanks !